# Code coverage in gitlab CI/CD

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, code-coverage, gitlab-ci

I used `Docker-dind` to build and test my python code. I confused how to run coverage in `gitlab-ci` between two following options.

1) Gitlab has coverage by itself [[here]](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#coverage)

2) I follow python's coverage [tutorial](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.5.1/cmd.html) and create my own coverage with following:

```
 coverage:
  stage: test
  script:
      - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
      - docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE python -m coverage run tests/tests.py
      - docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE python -m coverage report -m
```

When gitlab throws an exception `No data to report.`:

[image]

I guess `coverage report` command can not access/find `.coverage` file in the container.

---

So my question is What is the elegant way to run `coverage` in this situation?

Comment: I don't think gitlab has code coverage.  Instead, it allows you to extract code coverage from job output.

Comment: @emory would you please give me an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess coverage report command can not access/find .coverage file in the container.

Yes, your assumption is correct. By running:

```
- docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE python -m coverage run tests/tests.py
- docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE python -m coverage report -m
```

you actually start two completely separate containers one after the another.

In order to extract coverage report you will have to run `coverage report` command after the `coverage run` command is finished in the same container like so (I'm assuming bash shell here):

```
-  docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE /bin/bash -c "python -m coverage run tests/tests.py && python -m coverage report -m"
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, while it solve the issue I face into another problem and gitlab doesnt report coverage. I also add test coverage parsing

Comment: Can you then, please, expand question with details about that another issue you are facing and give some minimal example? Do you use artifacts to persist coverage or have other approach?

Comment: This was so helpful @Const. Thanks a lot. A curious question though, and anyone here who knows can answer me, what do the " -c "  and "-m" options mean in the above script?

Answer (score 8):

since [const's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50885461/4693568) has already made the first part easier i.e to get the coverage details, I have tried solve `how to get reports?`

This is given by [Gitlab coverage doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#coverage).
So your `coverage` job must be written like this

```
 coverage:
  stage: test
  script:
      - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
      - docker run $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE /bin/bash -c "python -m coverage run tests/tests.py && python -m coverage report -m"
  coverage: '/TOTAL.+ ([0-9]{1,3}%)/'
```

the regex was mentioned in [mondwan blog](https://mondwan.blogspot.com/2017/05/unit-test-on-python-coverage-report.html)

## Addon

If you add the below line in your `README.md` file you will get a nice *badge*(in master README.md) that captures your coverage details.

`[![coverage report](https://gitlaburl.com/group_name/project_name/badges/master/coverage.svg?job=unittest)](https://gitlaburl.com/group_name/project_name/commits/master)`

[image: coverage scrrenshot]